# Jmeter master slave setup in AWS instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, jmeter, load-testing

I have a task of doing distributed load testing using jmeter . Can someone help me with setup process for aws instances and configuration of jmeter in slaves ? Also jmeter master slave configuration ?

Comment: What about reading the [Jmeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html) and [Google](http://google.com) is your friend....

Comment: @RayOei Configuration of Jmeter distributed testing is not working on AWS instances. i am also stuck with same above issue.

Comment: What configuration at aws are you trying to implement? Any ec2 instances, vpc? Or what?